# Efficient way to count frequency of values in an array while keeping the space if no element value exists

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large 1d NumPy array that has values between [0, 6]. For example, suppose `A = [0, 0, 2, 4, 4]`

I want to create the following array from A: `B = [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]`

This is because there are 2 0s in A, 0 1s in A, 1 2s in A, 0 3s in A, 2 4s in A, 0 5s in A, 0 6s in A.

I am not sure what the most efficient method is to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `np.bincount`

```
In [944]: np.bincount(A, minlength=7)
Out[944]: array([2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the elements of `A` be between [0,n]. Create B as `[0]*(n+1)`. Then use a simple loop:

```
B = [0]*(n+1)
for i in A:
    B[i] += 1
print(B)
```

Comment: Yes, I know this is an option... I was hoping there is a better way than this (using numpy or counter or something)

Comment: i'd say writing a simple loop is arguably more efficient than importing a library (or library function) for a single use-case

Comment: @PranayAgrawal this is a simple and clean method. If you wanted something else, you should've specified in the question

Comment: @VictorVulovic I think you would get a different opinion from many `numpy` users; besides, the OP seems to be already using `numpy`.

Comment: i'd agree with you @hilberts_drinking_problem if OP was performing something like a multi-dimensional cross-product process, for example. To clarify my point, the OP's specific example is so simple/atomic that using numpy or some other library won't provide any additional meaningful increase in performance to using Abhinav's solution

Comment: Sorry, I do agree that my question could have been worded better. Let me clarify that I am running this operation independently about 1 million times (I cannot combine this into one np array). @AbhinavMathur Are you saying that if I had a 1 million 1x500k arrays (and cannot combine the 1 million independent arrays together), that a simple for-loop is still relatively as fast as other methods?

Comment: @VictorVulovic I see a speedup by a factor of 60-80 from `np.bincount` relative to pure Python solution. Since OP mentions efficiency in the question, this seems significant.

Comment: If I were working with large data, I would've made it a point to mention that as well. Your question only mentioned you had a numpy array, no other significant details otherwise. Next time mention the size of data you're working on

Comment: point taken, @hilberts_drinking_problem. Thanks to Andy L. for providing the constructive example upon which you base your conclusion